# How do I stop my Bootstrap Webpage (under development) from refreshing automatically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, page-refresh

**Explanation of issue:**

Hi.

I'm developing a personal webpage using HTML and CSS. I have also incorporated Bootstrap and a number of its components to achieve responsiveness.

I'm using Locally linked Bootstrap file/folder (not the online CDN). I want to use Locally downloaded Bootstrap until I have finished development.

However, I'm having difficulty testing all the features of the site sufficiently, especially the carousel component which features multiple gallery photos, because it keeps refreshing on me and this is really disruptive.

In other words, while testing something or clicking through the photo gallery, before I go through a quarter of the entire photos in the gallery, the page will suddenly refresh itself, causing me to start my testing afresh and this never ends.

**Question:**

How can I disable auto-refresh on the site or at least to set it to a very large value, so it doesn't disrupt my work?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide some details about your development setup.

Comment: I'm using VS Code. I downloaded bootstrap folder from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/download/ and stored it locally in my local webpage folder.

Then at head section of my HTML, I linked to it from my local site folder using the script tage as so: <script src="bootstrap-5.2.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

This way, I do not rely on internet connection to have bootstrap and bootstrap components work on the page, since it is now linked to my HTML file from the one I downloaded on the local hard drive.

But  the constant page refresh disrupts workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I have finally figured out the solution.

While I was going through my HTML Code and reviewing the meta tags in the  section of the code, I discovered that I had put a refresh value somewhere as one of the open graph meta tags. I had used a boilerplate code from somewhere which included a refresh rate of 30 seconds in the meta tag.

In essence, I had copied the boilerplate in addition with the meta tag and the refresh value along with others, while I was putting meta tags for the webpage.

I decided to comment out this piece of meta refresh tag and now, the web page is no longer refreshing automatically.

Below is the code:

```
<!-- END OF OPEN GRAPH SECTION -->


  <!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
```

Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).